# how to play different sounds with different activity in the same application in android?

Tags: android, audio

i am the beginner of android developer. i have some problem with sound. i develop English alphabet application. i want when we click on the picture it will play sound. and we can go to next letter by click button next. i can play sound in the first activity but when i go to next activity i can't play sound but if i change the second activity to the first activity i can play. how can i fix this? Please Help. Thanks

first activity

```
    MediaPlayer song;
    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            song=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
            song.start();
        }
    });

    apple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            song=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.apple);
            song.start();
        }
    });
```

second activity:

```
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            song1=MediaPlayer.create(B.this, R.raw.b);
            song1.start();
        }
    });
    book.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            song1=MediaPlayer.create(B.this, R.raw.book);
            song1.start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change B to the name of the second activity

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        song1=MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.b);
        song1.start();
    }
});
book.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        song1=MediaPlayer.create(SecondActivity.this, R.raw.book);
        song1.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: actually b is the name of the secondactivity! :(